# Organizar mensagem da Thread

Tags: java, rmi

boa noite.

Preciso da ajuda de vocês em algo meio simples, estou fazendo uma chat via RMI, a implementação do programa já está funcionando mais o menos como eu quero, mas eu to quebrando a cabeça em um simples print.
Eu preciso organizar a saída para que fique da seguinte maneira:

Chat: digitar mensagem

fulano de tal diz: mensagem digitada

Meu programa uma uma thread para ler as mensagens do servidor, e é justamente essas mensagens que não estou conseguindo organizar.

atualmente as mensagens estão saindo da seguinte forma:

Chat: Digitar Mensagem

Chat: fulano de tal diz: mensagem digitada

Ou seja, eu gostaria de seguir a sequeência

Mensagem

Mesagem

Sei que é meio besta essa dúvida, mas eu realmente não estou conseguindo fazer isso kkkk
segue meu codigo:

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatCliente{

private static Scanner scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        ChatIF chat = (ChatIF) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1098/Chat"); //Buscando a Interface no Servidor

        String nome;
        String msg = "";
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cont = chat.getmensagens().size();

        //Recebendo o nome do Usuario
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("       SEJA BEM VINDO AO CHAT                ");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("[Chat] Por Favor, Digite seu nome: ");
        nome = scanner.nextLine();

        //Thread responsavel por ler as mensagens do servidor
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            int cont = chat.getmensagens().size();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true){
                        if (chat.getmensagens().size() > cont){


   System.out.println(chat.getmensagens().get(chat.getmensagens().size()-1));
                            cont++;
                        }
                    }
                }catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Ola, " + nome + "! Voce agora esta conectado!");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

        thread.start();

        //Envia as mensagens  para o servidor
        while(true){
            System.out.print("[Chat]"+": ");
            msg = scanner.nextLine();           
            chat.setMensagem(nome+" diz"+": "+msg);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro: " + e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que as duas threads estão imprimindo na mesma console.

Nesse ponto você imprime a string chat sem quebra de linha.

```
while(true){
    System.out.print("[Chat]"+": "); // Aqui você imprime o "[Chat]:" sem quebra de linhas
    msg = scanner.nextLine();           
    chat.setMensagem(nome+" diz"+": "+msg);
}
```

Nesse outro ponto, você imprime a mensagem na mesma console da mensagem anterior.

```
System.out.println(chat.getmensagens().get(chat.getmensagens().size()-1));
```

Por isso você está vendo: "[Chat]: mensagem".
As mensagens das threads estão misturadas. Para que fique organizado você precisa colocar as threads em classes diferentes e criar um main para cada uma. Depois você precisa executar os dois main. Dessa forma você terá duas consoles.